# qsort Filling Array With Zeroes?

Tags: c, sorting, qsort

I am trying to sort an array of unsigned longs. However, for some reason the qsort is filling the entire array with zeroes rather than sorting it. I'll show my call to the function, comparator, and GDB.

This image shows the array before and after qsort, as well as my call to the function.

[image: GDB]

Here's the call:

```
qsort(scores[c], sizeof(scores[c]), sizeof(scores[c][0]), comparator);
```

Here is my comparator function called comparator:

```
int comparator(const void *p, const void *q)
{
      if( *((unsigned long *)p) < *((unsigned long *)q)){
          return -1;
      }
      else if( *((unsigned long *)p) == *((unsigned long *)q)){
          return 0;
      }
      else{
          return 1;
      }
}
```

What causes this and what can I do about it?

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code, but actual code as text. An image doesn't allow the post to appear in searches. Also, make sure it is a proper [mcve], and not just bits and pieces which may not reproduce the issue.

Comment: I also seriously doubt you this is both a C, and C++ question. You are most definitely compiling only as one of those.

Comment: Unless `scores[c]` is an array of `char` or `unsigned`, then `sizeof scores[c]` is not going to give the number of elements to sort. Why are you using `scores[c]` as the 1st parameter anyway instead of `scores`??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`qsort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/qsort) parameter `sizeof(scores[c])` gives the size in bytes, not the number of elements to be sorted.

You probably get lots of out-of-range accesses that happens to pick up the zeros.

Comment: Thanks so much! I thought qsort took in total array size and element size, turns out it takes in element count and element size.